# Array value does not change

Tags: php, arrays

I guess it is has something to do with [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) because `$this` and the objects in `$this->products[$key]` do implement ArrayAccess. However there is no magic `__get` or `__set` anywhere.

```
var_dump($this->products[$key]['selected_options'][$option_key]);
// Output: string(7) "Größe:S"

$this->products[$key]['selected_options'][$option_key] = "test";

var_dump($this->products[$key]['selected_options'][$option_key]);
// Output: string(7) "Größe:S"
```

Does someone have any idea what is wrong here?

Also note that this does work:

```
$this->products[$key]['selected_options'] = array($option_key => "test");
// Output: string(4) "test"
```

ArrayAccess for Products same for `$this` (Cart) but with `$products` instead of `$data`:

```
class Product implements ArrayAccess
{
    protected $data;

    /* **** ArrayAccess **** */
    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->data[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return $this->data[$offset];
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset , $value) {
        $this->data[$offset] = $value;
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->data[$offset]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to tell us what $value is?

Comment: @Paul `Output: string(7) "Größe:L" ` :)

Comment: Yes. @OP: Did you test those lines exactly as presented here? No other code in between?

Comment: @Paul to make it more simple: assiging a string does not work. see update.

Comment: @phant0m yes, exactly as presented here. Wired I know.

Comment: Are there any magic getters involved?

Comment: Show the code of the ArrayAccess implementation. (I have removed your mentioning of the multi-dimensional array, that's misleading)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return by reference inside `offsetGet`.

[**From the manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetget.php):

> While direct modification triggers a call to *`ArrayAccess::offsetSet()`*, indirect modification triggers a call to *`ArrayAccess::offsetGet()`*. In that case, the implementation of *`ArrayAccess::offsetGet()`* must be able to return by reference, otherwise an *`E_NOTICE`* message is raised.

Note, however, that this only works with PHP >= 5.3.4

Comment: I added an & in `public function &offsetGet($offset) {` any now it works. Perfect, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You might be trying to change [an immutable property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7317164/427992).

How is `$this->products` defined? What is its visibility? You'll need to look into the scope of the current class and see whether properties can be overwritten after instantiation.

Comment: I added the class definition. $this->products is an array of Products.

Answer (score 0):

Well i ran this:

```
// INPUT: string(7) "Größe:S"
$products = array();

$key = 1;
$option_key = 1;

$products[$key]['selected_options'][$option_key] = "badgers";

$products[$key]['selected_options'][$option_key] = "xxx";

var_dump($products[$key]['selected_options'][$option_key]);
```

And the output was:

> string(3) "xxx"

So more code is needed i think?